# How to apply blockquote to UIWebView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I'm using the [following Wordpress Editor Framework](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Editor-iOS) to offer the User a Rich Text editor.

[image]

The resulting String is:

```
"<b>Bold is working&nbsp;</b><i>Italic as well</i>\n<blockquote>But sadly... blockquote is not\n<ul>\n\t<li>Lists are working</li>\n</ul>\n</blockquote>"
```

My idea, to display the final String in the same format was to use a `UIWebView`.

```
let result = "<b>Bold is working&nbsp;</b><i>Italic as well</i>\n<blockquote>But sadly... blockquote is not\n<ul>\n\t<li>Lists are working</li>\n</ul>\n</blockquote>"
contentWebView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><font face='SourceSansPro' color='black'>\(result)</font></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

Pretty much everything is the way I want it to be, but the blockquote.

How can I apply the blue/grey background to the blockquote as in the first screen?

[image]

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Well, your string isn't applying any style to the blockquote, that's why you're not seeing any color.  I'm sure the editor is referencing a CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround:

```
func getFormattedHTMLString(_ entryString: String) -> String {
    let cssStyle = "<style>div {border: 0px solid black;background-color: #E1E8F2;padding-top: 10px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-left: 10px;}</style>"
    let removedBlockquoteEntries = entryString.replacingOccurrences(of: "<blockquote>", with: "<div>")
    let removedBlockquoteEndings = removedBlockquoteEntries.replacingOccurrences(of: "</blockquote>", with: "</div>")

    let result = "<html><head>\(cssStyle)</head><body><font face='SourceSansPro' color='black' size='5'>\(removedBlockquoteEndings)</font></body></html>"
    return result
}
```

I have added CSS Code to the String as well as HTML tags.

Then I have replaced `<blockquote>` tags with `<div>` tags.

Usage: `webView.loadHTMLString(getFormattedHTMLString(txt), baseURL: nil)`

Resul:

[image]